# Como obtener el valor de un atributo en una etiqueta html con JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Amigos Lo que pasa es que necesito capturar el valor de un atributo de una etiqueta html en este caso.

`<input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data="@item.MunicipalityId" />`

esta etiqueta la tengo dentro de un ciclo for es decir me crea aproximadamente 3 elementos con la misma clase 'link1'

```
<table class="table">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Municipalities)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditMunicipality", new { id = item.MunicipalityId }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" }) |
                            <input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data="@item.MunicipalityId" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
</table>
```

y necesito hacer que JQuery me capture ese valor al botón que el usuario de click, esto quiere decir que cada un botón del ciclo me va a traer un atributo data diferente. así lo he hecho yo

```
<script>
    $('.link1').click(function () {
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }, function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteMunicipality")',
                data: { MunicipalityId: $(this).attr("data") },
                datatype: "html",
                //success: function (data) {
                //    //codigo
                //}
                success: function () {
                    var MunicipalityId = $(this).attr("data");
                    if (MunicipalityId == null) {
                        swal('Deleted!',
                             'Your imaginary file has been deleted.',
                             'success'
                             );
                    } else {
                        swal("Oops", "The record can't be delete.(has related records)", "error");
                    }
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!" + ex, "error");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Y siempre me captura es el primero de la lista, independiente del botón al que le de click. Gracias es lo que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Puedes pegar el código completo del for?

Comment: Vale lo voy a editar

Comment: Listo amigo lo puedes ver?

Answer (score 2):

Reemplazando el

```
 $(this).attr("data")
```

por

```
 $(this).data("municipalidad")
```

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.link1').click(function(){
    var result = { data: { MunicipalityId: $(this).data("municipalidad") } };
    alert(result.data.MunicipalityId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data-municipalidad="municip01" />
<input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data-municipalidad="municip02" />
<input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data-municipalidad="municip03" />
```

**Actualización**

```
 <input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data-municipalidad="@item.MunicipalityId" />
```

Comment: cada vez que tengas que utilizar varios campos a utilizar, te recomiendo que hagas el data-loquedesees y tendrás mayor control de lo que se hace :D

Comment: No amigo no funciona

Comment: limpiaste la caché del navegador?

Comment: por cierto, creo que te falta actualizar un detalle, ahorita actualizo la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

¿Cómo estableces el controlador del evento click de los botones?

No deberías tener mayor problema para recuperar el valor.

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.link1').click(function(){
    var result = { data: { MunicipalityId: $(this).attr("data") } };
    alert(result.data.MunicipalityId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data="municip01" />
<input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data="municip02" />
<input class="btn btn-danger link1" type="button" value="Delete" data="municip03" />
```

Comment: mira como lo hago pero no me agarra dice que esta vacio :(